# Is the electric field only a pictorial representation of the electric force or it has some deeper role to play?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I was told in the class that Micahel Faraday introduced the concept of field to explain how two bodies without touching each other exert forces on each other. Then in electrostatics, we read about electric field **defined as electric force per unit charge** and then how we join these electric field vectors at various location around a charged particle to get electric field lines. Finally, we saw how the spacing between these lines could tell us about the strength of the electric field. All of this is to me only a pictorial representation of the force given by the Coulomb's law (base of electrostatics). But I read somewhere that the electric field has a deeper role in electrodynamics. I don't have very much understanding of either electrostatics or electrodynamics but could anyone please throw some light on the real role of bringing in the concept of electric fields from a layman's perspective.

Comment: your readings are correct. you have encountered a topic upon which great textbooks have been written; the true challenge is explaining the rudiments  in layman's terms, because the  field (no pun intended) (OK maybe pun intended) is phrased most concisely in the language of mathematics. This particular forum might not be the best for helping you with this; but perhaps one of the experts here could recommend for you a text which would be suitable for this purpose.